# INITRAMFS installation error

Tags: server, system-installation, initramfs

I have a new Powerspec B677 and I'm trying to install Ubuntu server on it. I verified the SHA256 and burned the USB with Rufus. Rufus asked me if I wanted to download the additional files with it because it was missing some and I said yes. Now I'm getting an [     0.458573] INITRAMFS unpacking failed: decoding failed message and the installer starts writing a bunch of stuff on the screen really really small and the characters are incomplete, so it is illegible. It looks like it's installing or trying to install. But I can't read it because it looks like The Matrix except right to left. Every so often when trying this I do get a menu but if I don't act quick enough it starts installing and I get the same problem. If I get lucky I can choose the installer option but I get the same message and garbling across the screen. I've tried this about 20 times and I also made the ISO USB at work just to see if that would change things and I got the same messages and problems.

Does anybody know what I should do?

Comment: Try using [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to write the iso to the USB stick. You only have to select the iso and the USB stick and press ok.

Comment: Okay I will do that Max and let you know how it works out. I appreciate the answer

Comment: The same thing happened with Etcher. I think it might be my PC - maybe the UEFI (ASRock H310CM-HDV/M.2 P4.20U).

Comment: I did use another option when the menu came up and it did install. But then I got the crazy matrix type printing again after installation. My next step is to remove the video card and use the system board video to one screen and retry. I did manage to get a photo of a failure to dismount cdrom during the installation. I'm going to bed and I will try it again tomorrow after work with the single monitor, removed video card.

Comment: try a different USB device / port, try a different ISO, etc.  Process of elimination is your friend

Comment: Will do, Nmath, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the video card and attempted to install. I still got the INITRAMFS unpacking and decoding failure, but it did install. The video card was the problem. Thank you for your help and responses.